# Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Find dimension and one basis of $\text{span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)\cap \text{span}(e_1,e_2+e_3)$.

Tags: vector-spaces

$B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$

To find matrices in $\operatorname{span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)\cap \operatorname{span}(e_1,e_2+e_3)$ we solve a system:
$a        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}=b\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow a=b=0\Rightarrow$ $\operatorname{span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)\cap \operatorname{span}(e_1,e_2+e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow$

$\dim (\operatorname{span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)\cap \operatorname{span}(e_1,e_2+e_3))=0$.

**Question**: What is a basis of $\operatorname{span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)\cap \operatorname{span}(e_1,e_2+e_3)$?

Is it $\left\{        \begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0   \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ or $\left\{        \begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0   \\
        0   \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right\}$?

Comment: The zero vector cannot be part of any basis. The empty set $\;\emptyset\;$ is the (only) basis for the zero subspace. And you calculation is wrong: at least the vector $\;e_1+e_2+e_3\;$ is in both spans.

Comment: @Joanpemo Could you show the method for finding $\cap$ of two spans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;a,b,\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R\;$ , so some vector belongs to that intersection iff

$$a(e_1+e_2)+be_3=\alpha e_1+\beta(e_2+e_3)\iff (a-\alpha)e_1+(a-\beta)e_2+(b-\beta)e_3=0\iff$$

$$\iff a=b=\alpha=\beta$$

and thus

$$\text{Span}\{e_1+e_2,e_3\}\cap\text{Span}\{e_1,e_2+e_3\}=\text{Span}\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Comment: I don't understand how did you get $span(1,1,1)$ when $a=b=\alpha=\beta$ should be equal to zero?

Comment: @user300044 Look at the left side of the first equation: it has to be $\;a=b\;$ , so any vector in the intersection is of the form $$\;a(e_1+e_2+e_3)=a\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ Why do you think  $\;a=b=\beta=\alpha\;$ should be zero?

Comment: Is it correct that to form a basis, we need to find two more vectors that are linearly independent and span $\cap$ of those two spans? The dimension of $\cap$ is then $3$.

Comment: @user300044 I'm not sure I understand your question. The dimension of the intersection cannot be three else it'd be the whole space, which is absurd since each ofthose spans is generated by ONLY two vectors so the dimension is at most two. What is shown in my answer is that the dimension is actually one.

Comment: And a basis is $(1,1,1)$, right?

Comment: @user300044 Yes. Any other non-zero vector in the intersection can be a basis, of course. This one seems to me the simplest.